# Symfony 5 onAuthenticationSuccess not being triggered

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using **Symfony 5.3.1** and I'm implementing the default authentication system.

1. php bin/console make:user
2. php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
3. php bin/console make:auth
4. php bin/console make:registration

When I register a new user using the automatically created register template is perfectly working and the user is added to my MySQL database.

But, when I log in a user in the /login template nothing happens. No redirect. No error.

What I expect is onAuthenticationSuccess being called from /Security/LoginAuthenticator.

**This is my /Security/LoginAuthenticator**

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\PassportInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
    {
        $username = $request->request->get('username', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $username);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($username),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->get('_csrf_token')),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }
        
        // For example:
        //return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

**This is my security.yaml:**

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/experimental_authenticators.html
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                target: link.index
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginAuthenticator

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**And finally this is my SecurityController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", priority=10, name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // if ($this->getUser()) {
        //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
        // }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", priority=12, name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

I have being 2 days looking for a solution and nothing worked. Here is a picture of my login form:

[image: Login form symfony]

After clicking Sign in, the page is refreshed and nothing happens.

Thank you.

Comment: This is my git repository: https://github.com/jacintofleta/symfony

Comment: You need to uncomment the redirect line in the onAuthenticationSuccess.  It's been a bit of a puzzle for me as to why they did not just put in some sort of default redirect.  You should have seen the exception.  You have something else going on preventing it.

Comment: Hello @Cerad thank you for your comment. If I uncomment I don't see anything. The exception is also not being executed. Is like the onAuthenticationSuccess method is never being called.

Comment: Make sure you are in development mode.  Add a dump and die statement to onAuthenticationSuccess to confirm if the method is or is not being called.  In what you posted I am not seeing the debug bar at the bottom of the screen.  You need a full html page to see the debug bar and you need the debug bar to track down these sorts of issues.

Comment: Also consider checking in your .env file.  Make sure there are no passwords in it.  I took a look at your repo but I also need to look at the .env file just to make sure you are not doing anything funky.

Comment: I took a close look at your repo.  composer.json seems to be missing the entire require-dev section which explains why the profile/debug bar is not show up.  Consider starting over with a fresh 'symfony new --full project' install and make sure your home page shows up with the profile bar.  At the very least you will get the full error pages showing up.

Comment: @Cerad thank you so much, I have solved the issue using a php server instead of the server I got with the bitnami MAMP program.

I have also activated the dev bar, thank you so much for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

I was using a server from bitnami MAMP and I changed to:

**php -S localhost:8000 -t public**

This solved my problem.

Credits to the youtube channel "Art of coding" who figured out this and helped me. Credits also for the user Cerad who also helped me.

Comment: You really should consider installing the Symfony CLI and then just using 'symfony server:start'.  It's all in the docs.